# function to filter in two steps based on common values ​of two columns ("two columns crossed filter")

Tags: r

Can anybody suggest a R function to filter in two steps or "crossed filter between two columns" based on common values ​​of two columns. first step would be to find common values ​​that are in columns C and F (in this case rowF and rowH), second step would be to use the values of D that passed first filter (on the left of rowF and rowH, so rowA and rowB) to look for common values ​​between columns A and D.

| A | B | C | D | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FFFFFi | ro1 | rowF | rowA | rowE |
| Second | ro3 | rowH | rowA | rowF |
| rowA | ro3 | row | rowA | rowG |
| Fecond | ro3 |  | rowB | rowH |
| Hecond | ro3 |  | rowB | rowT |
| rowB | ro3 |  | rowB | rowX |

I want to know if there is a possibility in R.

result has to be

| A | B | C | D | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rowA | ro3 | row | rowA | rowG |
| rowB | ro3 |  | rowB | rowX |

When possible just with A,  B and C

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rowA | ro3 | row |
| rowB | ro3 |  |

i can only guess maybe first step?

If Data$C %in% Data$F

return (Datafilter1)

If Datafilter1$A %in% Datafilter1$D

return (Datafilter2)

Comment: Are those missing values `NA`?

Comment: How did you get `JAM` in `ITEM2` in the output

Comment: thanks for answering and sorry first table was a mess i have entered now a better format ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create your data frame with the example data you provided in R
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("FFFFFi", "Second", "rowA", "Fecond", "Hecond", "rowB"),
  B = c("ro1","ro3","ro3","ro3","ro3","ro3"),
  C = c("rowF", "rowH", "row", "", "", ""),
  D = c("rowA", "rowA", "rowA", "rowB", "rowB", "rowB"),
  F = c("rowE", "rowF", "rowG", "rowH", "rowT", ""))


# Filtering based on common values in columns C and F
df1 <- df %>%
  filter(C %in% F)

#Finally Filtering based on common values in columns A and D
result <- df %>%
  filter(D %in% df1$D & A %in% c("rowA", "rowB")) %>%
  select(A, B, C)

#outpu
result
     A   B   C
1 rowA ro3 row
2 rowB ro3
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot call `c("rowA", "rowB")` since you do not know before hand what it will be.

Comment: Oops! you are right. You mean creating uniqe A before final result?

Comment: onyanmbu is right...rowA and rowB could be whatever value, sorry for the confusion, thanks anyway